# KnockoutJS + WebAPI 2 Token Authentication - maintain login state until token expires

Tags: authentication, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api, knockout.js, bearer-token

I'm fairly new to token based authentication and I have a problem of how to maintain login state after I login.
I want to create a SPA website for which I am using Knockoutjs for my front end and SammyJS for routing and changing the views.
After I login in and get the token I store it in localStorage and set the username into an observable which I am displaying.

My problem is that after I close the tab or browser and I go back to the site, the token is in the localStorage but I can't see the user logged in. 
I want to maintain the login state until the token expires. My question is what should I do with the token from the localStorage when I enter the site in order to maintain the login state of that user?

Do I need to make something in the startup class or to check if that user exists in the DB?

Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

**StartupAuth.cs**

```
    [assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(EventHub.PL.WebUI.Startup))] namespace EventHub.PL.WebUI {
        public partial class Startup
        {
            public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get;private set; }
            public static OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions OAuthBearerOptions { get; private set; }
            public const string TokenEndpointPath = "/api/token";
            public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }
            // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
            public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
            {
                // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
                app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
                app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
                // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
                // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
                app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
                app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
                OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();
                // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
                PublicClientId = "self";
                OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
                {
                    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString(TokenEndpointPath),
                    Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
                    //AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
                    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
                    AllowInsecureHttp = true
                };
                // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
                //app.UseOAuthBearerTokens( OAuthOptions );
                app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthOptions);
                app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(OAuthBearerOptions); 
            }
         }
```

**AccountController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [Route("Login")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Login(LoginUser model)
        {
            var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
            var tokenServiceUrl = request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + request.ApplicationPath + "/api/Token";
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var requestParams = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", model.Email),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", model.Password)
                };
                var requestParamsFormUrlEncoded = new FormUrlEncodedContent(requestParams);
                var tokenServiceResponse = await client.PostAsync(tokenServiceUrl, requestParamsFormUrlEncoded);
                var responseString = await tokenServiceResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenResponse>(responseString);
                var responseCode = tokenServiceResponse.StatusCode;
                if (responseCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    RegisterUser user = userRepository.GetNameById(json.Id);
                    var data = new
                    {
                        status = "success",
                        json.access_token,
                        user.Lastname
                    };
                    return Json(data);
                }
                return Json(new { status = "failed" });
            }
        }
```

here is the **KO** part:

```
var LoginApp = function () {
    var instance = this;
    instance.mainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
    instance.loginViewModel = new LoginViewModel();
    instance.loginRepository = new LoginRepository();
    instance.loginViewModel.signIn = function() {
        $('.loader-header').show();
        var postData = {
            email: instance.loginViewModel.email(),
            password: instance.loginViewModel.password
        }
        instance.loginRepository.SignIn(SignInSuccess, postData);
    };
    instance.SignInSuccess = function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'success') {
            instance.mainViewModel.username(response.Lastname);
            instance.mainViewModel.isVisible(true);
            var userData = {
                token: response.access_token,
                username: response.Lastname
            };
            localStorage.setItem('AuthorizationData', JSON.stringify(userData));
            $('.loader-header').hide();
            dialog.close();
        } else {
            $('.loader-header').hide();
        }
    };
    instance.init = function () {
        ko.applyBindings(instance.loginViewModel, document.getElementById("signin-form"));
        ko.applyBindings(instance.mainViewModel, document.getElementById("main-wrapper"));
    }
    instance.init();
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    var loginApp = LoginApp();
});
```

**UPDATE**

here is my routing also

```
var appRoot = root;

(function ($) {
    var app = $.sammy('#page', function () {
        this.get('#/home', function (context) {
            document.title = 'Home - ' + title;
            var url = getUrlFromHash(context.path);
            loadView(url, new MainViewModel(), MainApp);
            //context.load(url).swap();
        });
        this.get('#/about', function (context) {
            var url = getUrlFromHash(context.path);
            loadView(url, new AboutViewModel(), AboutApp);
        });
        this.get('#/manage', function (context) {
            var url = getUrlFromHash(context.path);
            loadView(url, new AboutViewModel(), AboutApp);
        });
    });
    $(function () {
        app.run('#/home');
    });
})(jQuery);
function loadView(url, viewModel, callback) {
    $.get(url, function (response) {
        var $container = $('#page');
        //var $view = $('#page').html(response);
        $container.html(response);
        callback();
    });
}
function getUrlFromHash(hash) {
    var url = hash.replace('#/', '');
    if (url === appRoot)
        url = 'home';
    return url;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now all you're doing is storing the user's credentials in localStorage but not using them to perform authorization. One alternative is to use the Sammy.OAuth2 plugin (which you can find it [here](https://github.com/quirkey/sammy/blob/master/lib/plugins/sammy.oauth2.js)).

You can define a route to make the authentication like:

```
app.post("#/oauth/login", function(context) {
    this.load('http://yourwebsite/login',
        {
            cache: false, 
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                email: $("input[name=email]").val(), 
                password: $("input[name=password]").val()
            }
        })
        .then(function(content) {
            if(content != false){
                if(app.getAccessToken() == null){
                    app.setAccessToken(token());
                }
            }else{
                app.trigger("oauth.denied");
                return false;
            }
        });
});
```

In 'protected' routes you can check if the user is already logged in like this:

```
app.get("#/profile", function(context) {

    if(app.getAccessToken() != null)
        context.render('view/profile.template');
    else
        this.requireOAuth();

});
```

This examples will have to be modified to populate the token according to your scenario. Here's a complete tutorial on [Sammy.Oath2](http://codexc.com/blog/2015/01/sammy-js-oauth-and-login-tutorial/).

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am using login from a popup which I send to the controller, the '#/oauth/login' is the route to the controller, right? And i would need to make this check on the 'home' route, right? This is a bit unclear.

Comment: That's right -- in the first snippet you're sending the 'email' and 'password' to the server (i.e. Wep API controller) in a POST request to "#/oauth/login". The second snippet defines a route that checks if the user is authenticated already. If  that's the case then the user is directed to the desired page (i.e. "view/profile.template")

Comment: Ok, thanks! One more thing, the first snippet that I can use on a button click for sending it to the controller? Because for login/register I do not use any url like for other pages(#/about), it's just a popup and on a button I send the data to the controller. So i'm not quite sure how to use this approach. Something like I posted the routing part of  the website,but instead of get I use post? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes,one alternative would be to create a custom binding that checks if app.getAccessToken() is valid http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html